# Can't map crawled property to managed property

Tags: managed-property

I have a crawled property that I'm trying to map a managed property to.  I click map property, search and find it.  But there is no OK button?  Is this some odd security issue?  Please see image below:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a custom master page? That button isn't themed in a SharePoint native color. If you're using any custom master page or script, remove it and see if the button reappears.

Comment: Thanks Trevor.  A clever colleague of mine clicked the tab button and the screen scrolled far to the right and revealed the OK and Cancel buttons.  Thanks for your help though.  I thought it was another security issue!